# c# automation code

Tags: c#, javascript, testing, automation, ranorex

I need to write C# automation script for metro app testing. I am using ranorex tool. How do I launch the application present on metro UI through the script? If I record and play back, it doesn't work on the different system. Please suggest script to launch the metro app.
I do not know the folder/path to the metro app as it is hidden.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a framework called UIA provided by Microsoft for automating Windows 8 apps.
This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/09/04/automating-the-testing-of-windows-8-apps.aspx) would give you the brief idea.

Comment: Please provide a full answer, not just a link.